# change event is not detecting in angular 4 IE11

Tags: angular

I am building a Angular4 project using Angular CLI (1.4.9). change event is detecting in Chrome and firefox but when I tried to use IE11 change event is not detecting only:

Comment: Can you included your code?  Which change event are you talking about?  Is it one of the lifecycle hooks or the change event on a select DOM?

Comment: <input (change)="somefunction()" type="text">

Comment: Change should work in all browsers: [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is check your polyfills as the (change) event should get fired when you focus of the element if it has changed.

I don't know if this will work in your scenario or not but I know this will capture change events in IE11

```
<input (input)="somefunction($event)" type="text">


someFunction(event) {
  event.target.value // this will be the value of the input
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work in my scenario.The input event is triggered immediately after any mutation of the value property

Comment: I updated my answer.  Do you have the pollyfills enabled? In your pollyfills.ts?